# Why does get-product return no products in some regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the [get-products](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pricing/get-products.html) CLI to get pricing for ElastiCache instances in different regions.

I simply query on the number of prices returned and I get good results for some regions:

```
bash-5.0$ location='us east (ohio)'
aws pricing get-products --profile=redislabs --service-code=AmazonElastiCache --filter Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=Location,Value="$location" --output json --query 'length(PriceList)'
```

**Outputs:**

> 122

But other regions return 0 (e.g. 'europe (stockholm)')

```
bash-5.0$ location='europe (stockholm)'
aws pricing get-products --profile=redislabs --service-code=AmazonElastiCache --filter Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=Location,Value="$location" --output json --query 'length(PriceList)'
```

**Outputs:**

> 0

Why is this? Why would the pricing CLI return 0 results when I can go to the [AWS ElastiCache pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=5) and see that there are many prices for products in europe (stockholm)?

(I have tried changing the case of the location, but that makes no difference - it works whatever case the location is in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `location` == europe but the syntax is EU.

```
location='eu (stockholm)'

aws pricing get-products --profile=redislabs --service-code=AmazonElastiCache --filter Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=Location,Value="$location" --output json --query 'length(PriceList)'
```

Returns:

> 55

Comment: Thanks for the response! Much appreciated. I had thought that 'location' mapped to the SSM  `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/$REGION-CODE/longname` parameter, but I guess not - I'll have to go figure out how to get this `location` some other way!